# How manage multi language listings in the Android Market?

Tags: android, google-play

I have an app on the Android Market and has translation in several languages. However, on the market, it is listed in English only (That is, the description, what's new, title are in english only).

The market does have an option to list the app in multiple languages but I wonder how this work. Do I need to manually update each time each of the 'what's new' texts in each languages or is there some API that allow to upload the modified text at once?

I am trying to avoid having to manually uploading updated texts in N languages each time I release an app version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, you're out of luck. You need to rewrite in each language all of your text.

Comment: Yes, I know that I need to translate the text to each language but is there some form of bulk upload or do I need to manually paste the text of each language in the developer console?

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think so. The developer dashboard for Android has always been very feature-thin.